# CherryPy How to specifty multiple "actions" in get form?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I want the form to perform multiple actions after being submitted, rather than only one, the "generate" function. I have commented parts of the code that show my issue. Would appreciate help on how to specify multiple actions in a form.

```
import random
import string

import cherrypy


class StringGenerator(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <form method="get" action="generate"> 
#how to specify multiple actions here? want to include generate2, generate3 etc.
              <input type="text" value="8" name="length" />
              <button type="submit">Give it now!</button>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>"""

    @cherrypy.expose
    def generate(self, length=8):
        return ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
    #trying to add more functions like generate here that will be called when form is submitted like generate2, generate3, etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(StringGenerator())
```

Comment: Just perform all the things inside of the generate func

Comment: I would like to call multiple because I want new url pages for each function.

Comment: Then make HTTP calls with JS instead, it won't reload the page, though.